# How to set all Controls in wpf to unfocusable?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, focusable

I have a wpf application and I want to set everything to Focusable="false".
Is there an easy and elegant way? Currently I made a style for each type of Control I use like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
<Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Any idea for a more universan solution?

Comment: I posted an answer and i hope it'll help you.However, if you are a beginner with WPF, you can join my [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168245/beginners-of-wpf-join-here)

Comment: myWindow is the Name property of the window I gues, but I can't find the getChildren() function. What am I missing?

Comment: are u sure ?....

Comment: recheck my answer :)

Comment: 'System.Windows.Media.Visual' does not contain a definition for 'GetChildren' and no extension method 'GetChildren' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Media.Visual' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I get this error after inserting your code.

Comment: did u reference `System.Windows.Media.Visual` ??

Comment: System.Windows.Media.Visual is a class in the System.Windows.Media namespace and I have #using-ed that.

Comment: re-check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not try a two line solution ?

```
 foreach (var ctrl in myWindow.GetChildren())
{
//Add codes here :)
}
```

Also make sure to add this :

```
  public static IEnumerable<Visual> GetChildren(this Visual parent, bool recurse = true)
 {
if (parent != null)
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        // Retrieve child visual at specified index value.
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i) as Visual;

        if (child != null)
        {
            yield return child;

            if (recurse)
            {
                foreach (var grandChild in child.GetChildren(true))
                {
                    yield return grandChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Or even shorter, use this :

```
public static IList<Control> GetControls(this DependencyObject parent)
{            
    var result = new List<Control>();
    for (int x = 0; x < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); x++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, x);
        var instance = child as Control;

        if (null != instance)
            result.Add(instance);

        result.AddRange(child.GetControls());
    } 
    return result;
}
```